# How to play Angry Birds with 2007 MacBook's trackpad?

Tags: angry-birds

I can't play it using trackpad. Any settings?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently an update was released on Jan 11th that added support for older MacBooks. Seeing as the date of this post is one-day before that release, I presume you've got, or can get, things working now?